# First 100 primes javascript, why do I get undefined after my array of primes?

Tags: javascript

I get the 100 primes printed, but I also get undefined at the end. Why would that be?

```
function HundoPrimeNumbers() {
    var primes = [];

    function isPrime(n) {
        if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n % 1 || n < 2) return false;
        var m = Math.sqrt(n);
        for (var i = 2; i <= m; i++) if (n % i == 0) return false;
        primes.push(n);
    }

    var n = 0
    while (primes.length < 100) {
        isPrime(n);
        n++;
    }
    console.log(primes.join());
}

console.log(HundoPrimeNumbers());
```

Comment: Because `HundoPrimeNumbers()` doesn't return anything. http://jsfiddle.net/nile/dwPrQ/

Comment: This looks like part 1 from this week's homework for the Startup Engineering course :p.

Answer (score 3):

You are logging the result of `HundoPrimeNumbers`:

```
console.log(HundoPrimeNumbers());
```

`HundoPrimeNumbers` does not have a `return` statement. When a function doesn't have a return statement, or returns without a value, like `return;`, it actually ends up returning `undefined`. This then gets logged to the console.

Solution: call it like this:

```
HundoPrimeNumbers();
```

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is the return value of console.log()